# Fast algorithm of ARIMA-GARCH model selection

Tags: model-selection, garch, time-complexity, arfima

I use ARFIMA(p, x, q)-GARCH(P, Q) models for time series forecasting and when I calibrate models for selection the best via BIC criteria, I use "slow" approach when I calculate BIC for every `p*q*P*Q*count('norm', 'snorm', 'std', 'sstd', 'ged', 'sged')*count(sGARCH, eGARCH, gjrGARCH)*mean(YES/NO)*fixOmega(YES/NO)`
For p = q = 4, P = Q = 2 we have 4 608 models which inaccessiable,
For p = q = 3, P = Q = 1 we have 648 models.

I really suppose that potential models with greater parameter values can be more accurate, but it needs to much time/processor resources for calculation.

Is there any algorithms for calculation reduction?